# Can I import a package while excluding a certain class?

Tags: java, import, package

I am trying to import a package to my Main project, but I need to exclude a class. I know that I can individually import each class, but I have so many classes in this package that it would take much too long. Perhaps I can import the entire package, and somehow block the class I don't want?

Comment: "I have so many classes in this package that it would take much too long" - in what way? Normally you'd just ask your IDE to work out which imports you need... (If you need to import *that* many classes, perhaps the class doing the importing is too large?)

Comment: If you don't want a class in the import section then does it really belong to that package ?

Comment: @StackFlowed: I don't understand - do you always import *every* class within `java.util` whenever you import `java.util.Map` for example?

Comment: @JonSkeet I would not use import java.util.* i would end up using import java.util.Map. Moreover of the OP is taking about a package created by them.

Comment: Good IDEs (which you should be using) will detect if you need to import something, and will automatically import, asking you about conflicts. This is what you should use.

Comment: @StackFlowed: Sure, but reading your comment suggests that if you ever want to import just *some* of the classes from a package, the other classes probably don't belong in that package. If that's not what you meant, what *did* you mean?

Comment: What is this? Somebody arguing with the mighty Jon Skeet?!

Comment: @JonSkeet I ment was if you are creating a package and don't want a single class in that package to be imported when you use wild card on that package, then does it really belong to that package(or could me refactored to another package). PS I'm not taking about the Java library & the packages in that. I'm talking about the classes & package that are created by a programmer.

Comment: @Quincunx not arguing with the mighty Jon Skeet ! Trying to understand and learn more.

Comment: @StackFlowed: But surely it depends on the use case. It may be that for a *different* caller, they'd want all the classes in the package except some *other* class.

Comment: @JonSkeet so is it better to break the huge package in smaller fragments ?

Comment: @StackFlowed: Without knowing the context, we can't really say. We don't even know how "huge" the package is in this case.

Comment: @JonSkeet got ya ! Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot exclude classses from wildcard imports.

In truth, "import" is just syntactic sugar... Once a class is compiled, the full path names of all class references will be filled in. You can also fill in full class path references in your Java code. [Here's a link for more information](http://coderanch.com/t/400761/java/java/import-work-java)